# In nuxt.js how can access the slug values inside asyncData()?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

In nuxt.js am creating CMS content with dynamic url, i need to pass the slug value for ajax call, how can acces the slug value inside asyncData()

```js
export default {
   async asyncData({ app }) {
       const user = await app.$axios.$get(params.id);
       return { user };
   }
};
```

> URL : http://localhost:3000/myproj/12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had resolved the issue by passing `$axios` as the first argument in the `asyncData` functions

```
  export default {
       async asyncData({ $axios, params }) {
           const user = await $axios.$get(params.id);
           return { user };
       }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to pass extra prop - `params`, and then you have an access to `params`.

```
  export default {
       async asyncData({ app, params }) {
           const user = await app.$axios.$get(params.id);
           return { user };
       }
    };
```

Comment: I was tried to pass second parameter, but it is showing error...